# Can two devices connected to a VPN with the same account (Atlas, Nord, Express, etc) reach each other?

Tags: networking, vpn

The scenario I am looking to enable is for my devices to be able to reach each other without exposing them to the wide internet.

It seems it should technically be possible with the help of commercial VPN services such as Express/Atlas/NordVPN/etc.

I've tried googling but to no avail, can't seem to get a definitive answer whether several devices using the same account (obviously) of the commercial VPN service can reach each other when connected to a VPN.

Clarification: I have a work VPN, when I connect to it I can reach other computers/devices that are also connected to it. Is it possible to have this behavior with VPN any of the services?

Comment: I've learned that NordVPN has such feature called "Site-to-Site interconnectivity" with NordLayer product but it's unfortunately significantly more expensive than just pure VPN https://nordlayer.com/pricing/

Comment: In the end I followed a YouTube video for how to setup a custom PritunlVPN server on a linux VM using a free Oracle Cloud tier. Works fine.. except I would've loved to have that with a full VPN service with many server nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, yes, they could. If they connect to the same VPN node, they'll usually be in the same "subnet" (though it depends on the VPN implementation, but this should generally be the case for standard OpenVPN and WireGuard).

In practice, commercial VPN operators are likely to deliberately block direct client-to-client access, in order to prevent security issues (as the client OS may treat the VPN connection as a "trusted" or "workplace" network, its firewall unintentionally exposing file-sharing or other services).

Connections between hosts belonging to the same account are more likely to be allowed; some commercial VPN providers specifically mention that use case in their documentation – but it is just as likely that the system is not set up to care about which customer owns which address, and will simply block *any* traffic between any two VPN addresses. (It's much less effort for the operator than having the system somehow generate per-customer access lists.)

It would be better to search for a service that is specifically aimed towards such use – all of the services you've listed focus on providing "private" Internet access as their main product, which results in somewhat different architecture than direct client-to-client access.

Such services are often called "mesh" VPNs as they attempt to establish direct connections (through NAT traversal and other tricks), e.g. Tailscale or ZeroTier are commonly used for this purpose. In comparison, a connection through your Nord/Express account would relay everything through their servers and then back.

Comment: To clarify, I am fine with traffic going through their servers. When connecting to a VPN I assume a client gets a private IP for that network. The question is if the same account is used to connect to a VPN, can these two clients reach each other on their private IPs allocated to the VPN client.

Comment: My answer remains "in theory yes but the provider is likely to block it".